# How do I add a texture to one specific face?

Tags: texturing, shader-nodes

I'm really struggling with this part. I select a face, and then I drag the texture into the shader and click 'Assign', but the texture still appears across the whole model.
[image]

Answer (score 5):

This is default behaviour because you only have one material. The first material will always be applied to the whole mesh.

Create a second material, give it another color and click assign -> this works.